# Segmentation fault when I'm trying to overload operator<< for char

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

When I'm trying to overload operator<< for char and use it which `std::cout` something is wrong.During compilation I don't have any errors but when i type `./a.out`i see `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

This is code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & COUT, char letter)
{
    COUT << letter;
    return COUT;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << 'l';
}
```

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Your code has an infinite recursion. Your operator<< just calls itself. Since `basic_ostream` already has an operator<< defined for char, it's not clear why you are doing this.

Comment: You could have used the debugger to see the infinite recursion.  Why didn't you first use the debugger, and then ask about what you observed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the statement

```
COUT << letter;
```

will invoke your own overloaded function, leading to infinite recursion.

You need to explicitly call the "normal" overloaded function:

```
std::operator<<(COUT, letter);
```

---

On a different note, because the `<<` operator returns a reference to the stream, you can use it in your own function as a single statement:

```
return std::operator<<(COUT, letter);
```

---

For characters and strings, it's a [nonmember function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), for everything else it's a [member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). So for example `int` you need to call the member function instead:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, int value)
{
    return out.operator<<(value);
}
```